# Get correct file size from Spring MultipartFile

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

How to find correct file size from `org.​springframework.​web.​multipart.​MultipartFile`

```
double bytes = m.getSize();
double kilobytes = (bytes / 1024);
double megabytes = (kilobytes / 1024);     
 System.out.println(megabytes);
```

but its not giving the correct size.

Here `m.getSize()` return 2264855 but using this method it gives file size something 2MB but actual size in my system of file is 8MB

```
private HashMap add(@RequestParam( value = "files", required = false) MultipartFile[] mPartFile){

    if(mPartFile != null && mPartFile.length>0){
        for(MultipartFile m:mPartFile){
            if(!CoreServices.isSupportedFile(m.getContentType())){
                hm.put("status", MConstants.OPERATION_FAILED);
                hm.put("reason", "File: "+m.getOriginalFilename()+" is not supported. Upload only jpeg, png, gif image files.");
                return hm;                
            }
            long size = m.getSize();
            if( size> MConstants.MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE){
                hm.put("status", MConstants.OPERATION_FAILED);
                hm.put("reason", "File: "+m.getName()+" is not acceptable, its size is more than 5MB.");
                return hm;                
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

Here the value of `MAX_ALLOWED_FILE_SIZE` is `5000000` for 5MB limitation

Comment: actually one of these variables or all the vars (i.e. bytes, kilo and mega)?

Comment: i want to conver `m.getSize()` to MB

Comment: actual filesize and size on disk are different...what is the actual file size...of your file.

Comment: if i see in my desktop folder it shows around 8MB but when i use `getSize()` it shows 2264855 thats is arounf 2.3 MB

Comment: right click on the file and see properties. There are two sizes. Actual and size on disk. write both of the properties here...

Comment: i am using ubuntu an don right click it only show `Size :7.5 MB (75,38,686 bytes)`

Comment: then you just create a small text file with 10 bytes and see the result

Comment: i tested with a file whose size in my desktop show `9.4kb` in using `getSize` in my app shows `9584`

Comment: that means app is working fine. do a `ls -l` from terminal and get the size of both of the files.

Comment: Here is confusing result if check using `ls -l` in terminal for the big file it shows `7538686` but in my program it show `2264855` again for the smaller file both in terminal and in my program it show `9584`...how?

Comment: would you please paste your full code.

Comment: i updated my question.pls hv a look

Comment: would you try with a file near 5 MB? (such as 5000KB)

Comment: i checked with a file whose size on disk show `4.7 MB (47,13,978 bytes)` and in my app `840377`

Answer (score 6):

You are using method `getSize()` of MultipartFile, which I think returns size in bytes in binary.
So convert that to in MB you have to multiply `file.getSize()` with `0.00000095367432`. This will give you size in MB. You can verify [here](https://www.gbmb.org/bytes-to-mb).

I am using the same. I can see size of a file in windows is 18.9 KB which is actual size not the size on disk. In my case I need information in KB so I multiplied it by 0.0009765625 and it returned 18.9462890625 KB which is close to the size of file an may be windows is rounding it up.

I believe multiplying `file.getSize()` with `0.00000095367432` will work.